# Visual Studio adds extra indentation to functions inside class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, format

Checked the settings multiple times, but I can not seem to find a way to disable this behavior, when performing auto-formatting on a class (ex.: writing the closing bracket, which triggers auto-format), Visual Studio indents the function header, except for the first line, when the function is inside a class.

how a function looks (correctly), auto formatted, when it's not in a class:

```
_Check_return_
int
Double0(
    _In_ int Var
)
{
    return 2 * Var;
}
```

VS auto-indents the function this way:

```
class SampleClass0
{
    _Check_return_
        int
        Double1(
            _In_ int Var
        )
    {
        return 2 * Var;
    }
};
```

when i would like it to look like this:

```
class SampleClass1
{
    _Check_return_
    int
    Double2(
        _In_ int Var
    )
    {
        return 2 * Var;
    }
};
```

Indentation is respected only for the very first line of a multiline function, everything else until the code block is indented by one.

It seems, that ReSharper has an option to fix this but 1. it's not free 2. it's not automatic, and thus has to be run periodically.

Comment: There are  indentation and formatting [settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-c-cpp-formatting?view=vs-2019) in Visual Studio. Explore _Indentation_ and _New Lines_ tabs.

Comment: stop auto formatting

Comment: I am afraid that there is no direct way to meet your needs. However, you could create a custom format definition .clang-format or _clang-format file in `Tools->Options->Text editor->C/C++->Format->General`.

Comment: thanks, will see if that works, but worth noting, that ClangFormat is comes built-in only from vs2017 and up

Comment: If you succeed, you could write it down as the answer. It will be useful for me and others to learn new knowledge.